# MIPs code is giving several errors including: "address out of range", "overflow error", and continuous loop

Tags: assembly, mips

I have two arrays of integers that I am comparing A, and B that have 20 numbers each spanning from -500, +500. I am attempting to locate the index of the smallest distance.

```
.text
la $t0, A
la $t1, B
li $t2, 0 # Counter
la $t9, ArraySize # set at 19
li $t8, 10000 # Will only be used once for bgt

loop:
beq $t2, $t9, LoopEnd # loop end will print the output message and index w/ smallest distance
lw $t3, 0($t0) # A[i].x
lw $t4, 0($t1) # B[i].x **ADDRESS OUT OF RANGE ERROR**
lw $t5, 4($t0) # A[i].y, offset by 4 bytes 
lw $t6, 4($t1) # B[i].y, offset by 4 bytes

sub $t4, $t3, $t4
mul $t4, $t4, $t4

sub $t6, $t5, $t6
mul $t6, $t6, $t6

addu $t7, $t6, $t4 # **OVERFLOW ERROR WHEN SET AS add, AS addu ERROR GOES AWAY BUT I GET ADDRESS OUT OF RANGE ABOVE**

bgt $t7, $t8, pass # if less, execute code below
add $t8, $t2, $zero # add incrementor this will be printed at end

addi $t2, $t2, 1 # increase incrementor
addi $t0, $t0, 8 # increase position of array by 8 bytes
addi $t1, $t1, 8 # increase potision of array by 8 bytes

j loop # jump back to start of loop until it breaks with beq

pass: 
addi $t2, $t2, 1
addi $t0, $t0, 8
addi $t1, $t1, 8
j loop
```

Comment: Any one of those errors would stop the program instantly, so which one is it?  And how can it run continuously if it is stopped?

Comment: You forgot to show how `ArraySize` is defined.  Verify `$t9` is correct in your debugger. I suspect you might want `lw` not `la`.

Comment: @ErikEidt I should have added that detail. I believe the continuous loop was resolved when I added code to "pass". Before, I only had a j loop, which never incremented the counter. However, prior to switching "add" to "addu", I was getting an overflow error. After switching to "addu", the error that I am getting is "address out of range" which I have not been able to figure out how to correct.

Comment: Ok, why are you using `la` with `$t9` to obtain the value 19?  That should be an `li`, I would think, if that is a constant, or `lw` if a global variable.  Likely simply looping too many times.  Have you tried single stepping?  FYI, you can set your array size to 2 to make debugging easier.  Make sure it stops after 2!  Once you have control of the loop so it stops properly, probably other bugs will disappear.

Comment: @ErikEidt this is great advice. Thank you so much!